# possible traduction of the suspensive form/ と particle

Tags: grammar

when I have to make a translation I always find hard to translate the suspensive form. I know that I can translate it with "and", but can I translate it in a different way?
as in this case with "because"?

中学、高校**と**ずっと受験勉強に**追われて**、大学に入ってから突然遊び始める人も多いんですよね

and the と particole, how can it be translated? "With"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translate 中学、高校とずっと受験勉強に追われて as "Because they were busy preparing for their entrance exam, when they were in junior high school and high school".

I think literal translations are often unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

It's quotative と and it modifies adverb ずっと further adverbially.

This seems tough for learners to understand and explanation tends to get away with thinking 言う or 思う are omitted. This time, however, that doesn't work.

It's difficult to directly translate, so you have to express it with a different way like Yuuichi's.

Usual quotative usage is a subset of this. In this sense, it may be unreasonable to call it "quotative と" to begin with.

Relatively understandable example could be like this.

- 阿片の煙が雲と棚引き… : Clouds of opium smoke is floating